# Android: Layout collapse when soft keypad comes and action bar is also moving

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-scrollview, android-keypad

I've created registration screen with scrollview contains edittext and actionbar. When keypad opens layout getshrink for that i used adjustPan and adjustResize in androidmanifest file.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".UserRegistration"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize">
</activity>
```

And i used android:isScrollContainer="false" in scrollview.

**UserRegistration.xml**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">
  ....
</ScrollView>


EditText edtPhoneNo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobileno);
edtPhoneNo.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            edtPhoneNo.bringToFront();
            edtPhoneNo.invalidate();
            return false;
        }
});
```

Action bar should not be move when keypad opens and layout should not collapse.

Can anyone helps me to solve this issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<activity android:name=".UserRegistration"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
</activity>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply its working but edittext is not visible when keypad opens.

Comment: editText.bringToFront();
                    editText.invalidate();

that should do it.

Comment: edit your question and put the code where you click on the editText and when your keyboard appears.

Comment: EditText edtPhoneNo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobileno);
edtPhoneNo.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            edtPhoneNo.bringToFront();
            edtPhoneNo.invalidate()
            return false;
        }
});

Comment: @Kamal why did you accept the answer if you said it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand out of your English, try this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".UserRegistration"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```